# coding button to video

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.3

Program: android studio

hello
I'm trying to create a button that when I press on it, a full screen video show up. But the problem is when I set a VideoView it shows a gray screen on top of my play button.

What I want, is to make the VideoView invisible and completely white and use the button to play a full screen video without having any gray box covering my screen.

[image: the gray screen on top of my play button]

Comment: What is the question here ? If you don't want a View to be visible, use `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

Comment: I tried this, but it will hide the video as well

Comment: Just use `View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` when the user presses the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(false);
```

before playing the video, and

```
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

after `.start()`

Alternatively you can use

```
videoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Whichever one is applicable